# Do I need a copy stand to digitize negatives with a Sony Mirrorless Camera

Tags: sony, negative, digitizing

I want to digitize negatives with a Sony mirrorless camera. Do I need a copy stand?

Comment: Someone is not liking the question or the answers and seems to have downvoted everything. It is true that the question is oddly formulated. It more practical to ask *What do I need to digitize negatives with a Sony mirrorless camera?' rather than assuming that a copy stand may be involved.

Answer (score 2):

No. There are other ways. You can use a tablet or phone, light table, lens adapter, etc.  Google 'digitize negatives with digital camera` for options. Among top results you can see [one that uses a tablet](https://fstoppers.com/education/how-use-your-dslr-scan-negatives-137248) and another with a [light table](http://natephotographic.com/dslr-film-scanning-perfect-color-negatives/). Nikon makes a lens adapter for negatives too and it *may* fit some Sony lenses or you can use an adapter to fit a Nikon lens onto the Sony mirrorless.

Answer (score 1):

Copy stands are for duplicating prints and documents, not film. While you *can* use a copy stand with macro lens and light box, using a slide copier is far easier and cheaper.

Except for the film carrier, capture with a slide copier is the same for slides and negatives. The images also need to be processed differently. For negatives, the orange mask needs to be neutralized and colors inverted.

See [Using a 35mm Slide Copier with a Crop Sensor](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/102960/75526)

[image: slide copier]