# Is it better to shoot or scan a film negative for Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, film, negative-scanner, digitizing, film-scanner

Which one of these approaches produce better results with Lightroom later:

1. Scan the negative with a flatbed scanner (e.g., Epson V600); output Tiff image; then proceed with Lightroom.
2. Shoot your negative with a digital camera D750 (e.g. as Nikon Raw image); then proceed with Lightroom.

Comment: Generally speaking, modern digital cameras can quite easily surpass the scanning quality of flatbed scanner (albeit at a slower workflow)

Comment: [What are the major differences when digitizing slides/negatives with a DSLR vs. a scanner?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/11510/75526)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I get reasonably good results photographing negatives with a slide copier attachment and a macro lens (vs using a flatbed scanner). However, if you plan to scan many frames of film, you should consider a dedicated film scanner with batch feeder. Depending on your lens and camera, image quality from a film scanner may or may not be better, but it would be much more convenient.

**Flatbed (or film) scanner**

Advantages:

- Scanning negatives is an anticipated use case. Software usually include ability to invert and color correct negatives, often with single click.
- Scanner may have automated dust removal features (via additional infrared channel).
- No demosaicing.
- When image doesn't turn out well, it's most likely a problem with the film. (Don't have to constantly second guess scanner and settings.)
- Light source is built into the scanner. Results are consistent.

Disadvantages:

- Capture process can be slow. Scanning is done line-by-line.
- Focus and resolution of some scanners may not be optimal.
- Scanner takes up desk space.
- Scanner likely cannot extract "all" information from film (grain structure and dynamic range).
- Software usually automatically crops frame. May have difficulty capturing sprocket hole images. (More problem with film scanners than flatbeds.)

Other:

- Convenience, if using a film scanner with an automated feeder.
- Flatbed with transparency adapter is best (and most affordable) option for medium format.

**Digital camera with slide copier**

Advantages:

- Capture is fast (about the same as taking a picture).
- With good macro lens, can focus on image grain.
- With increased magnification ratio, can extract more information from image (grain and dynamic range).
- No scanner to occupy desk space.
- Reasonably affordable if you already own the camera and lens. (Slide copier attachments are ~$35-50.)
- Depending on attachment, can capture images that extend into sprocket holes.

Disadvantages:

- More time is spent post-processing images.
- Have to demosaic. Reduces resolution and may introduce artifacts.
- No automated dust removal.
- Photographing negatives is *not* a normal use case.

  - Camera may not meter properly.
  - White balance won't work properly.
  - Software is not designed to invert and color correct negatives. May have to spend lots of time tweaking curves.
  - When image doesn't turn out well, is it a problem with the film or camera or software? (Constantly have to second guess whether camera or software is at fault.)
- Focusing on grain can be difficult (depending on lens, magnification, and eyesight).

Other:

- Need to purchase a slide copier attachment.
- May need to purchase a suitable lens.
- Aberrations and distortions depend on lens.
- Contrast, sharpness, dynamic range depend on lens.
- For best results, have to use reproduction ratio greater than 1:1 and stitch.
- Depending on how careful you are, lighting may not be consistent across the frame.
- Medium format...

  - Difficult to find suitable slide copiers.
  - If using a lightbox, will likely have alignment problems.
  - Will likely have to stitch several images.

Comment: Also, flatbeds are just about the only affordable way to go if needing to scan in 120 or larger.

Comment: @Hueco I thought about discussing medium format, but wasn't sure if I should... guess I'll go ahead and add it.

Comment: I figured I'd mention it because I went through the whole "how do I get my film digitized" process and found that it gets really, really pricey when considering 120 and up. dedicated 35mm scanners aren't too bad. Dedicated 120 scanners are ridiculous imo.

Comment: @Hueco Cut medium format film into 35mm strips for scanning 

Comment: bwuahahahahah. oh the sacrilege. >_<